# Firestore:Javascript: How to convert user input into an array and storing it in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My program currently accepts a single user input on a certain category. If he/she deems that another field is needed, an add field button is available. Enter the question, how do I get all of these multiple user inputs for that certain category and turn them into an array field type so I can place it in Firestore? What is the correct way of querying the said input so that it would turn into an array when I view it in Firestore?

**Image of the program:**

[image]

**An example of what I want to see in my database:**

[image]

Do note that the field `allergies` in this image is already set as an array

**My Current Code:**

**This code is the user input or form code:**

```
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Allergy</label>
                                        <ul id="fieldList">
                                            <li>
                                                <input type="text" name="allergy" class="form-control" placeholder="Allergy" value="" id="allergy" required>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <button id="addMore">Add more fields</button>
                                        <script>
                                        $(function() {
                                            $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
                                                    e.preventDefault();
                                                    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='allergy' class='form-control' placeholder='Allergy' /></li>");
                                                });
                                            });
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
```

**This code gets all user input and does the `set` for Firestore:**

```
 //Register
    $('#registerForm').on('submit', async function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // var date_input = new Date($("#date_input").val());
      // var day = date_input.getDay();
      // var month = date_input.getMonth() + 1;
      // var year = date_input.getFullYear();
      // var theDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

      var data = {
        email: $('#email').val(), //get the email from Form
        firstName: $('#fname').val(), // get firstName
        lastName: $('#lname').val(), // get lastName
        allergies: $('#allergy').val(),
        sex: $('#sex').val(),
        birthDate: new Date($('#bday').val()),
        diabetesType: parseInt($('#dtype').val()),
        diabetesComplication: $('#dcomp').val(),
        weight: parseInt($('#weight').val()),
        height: parseInt($('#height').val()),
      };
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.birthDate);
      var passwords = {
        password : $('#password').val(), //get the pass from Form
        cPassword : $('#cpassword').val(), //get the confirmPass from Form
      }
      if( data.email != '' && passwords.password != ''  && passwords.cPassword != '' ){
        if( passwords.password == passwords.cPassword ){
          //create the user
          await firebase.auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, passwords.password)
            .then(function(user){
                console.log('uid',user.user.uid);
                usersRef.doc(user.user.uid).set({
                  'email': data.email, 'firstName': data.firstName, 
                  'lastName': data.lastName, 'allergies': data.allergies,
                  'sex': data.sex, 'birthDate': firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(data.birthDate),
                  'diabetesType': data.diabetesType, 'diabetesComplication': data.diabetesComplication,
                  'weight': data.weight, 'height': data.height,
             })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to answer if it is applicable to anyone, use JSON to serialize the array and convert to an array that firestore could store.

As for the process here is the code:

**HTML**

```
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Allergy</label>
                                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                                    <tr>  
                                                        <td><input type="text" name="allergy" id="allergy0" placeholder="Allergy" class="form-control name_list" /></td>  
                                                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                                    </tr>  
                                            </table>  
                                            <script>

                                             var i =  {
                                                    counter : 0,
                                                    button_id : 0,
                                                }  

                                            $(document).ready(function(){  
                                                $('#add').click(function(){  
                                                    i.counter++;  
                                                    i.button_id = i.counter;
                                                    console.log(i.counter);
                                                    console.log(i.button_id);
                                                    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i.counter+'"><td><input type="text" name="allergy" id="allergy'+i.counter+'" placeholder="Allergy" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
                                                });  
                                                console.log(i.counter);
                                                $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  

                                                    $('#'+"row"+i.button_id).remove();
                                                    i.button_id--;
                                                    i.counter--;  
                                                    console.log(i.button_id);
                                                    console.log(i.counter);
                                                });  
                                            });  
                                            </script>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Here is the code:

**JS**

```
  var allergyList = [];
  var cou = i.counter;
  for (c = 0; c <= cou; c++) {
    var allergyField = document.getElementById("allergy" + c).value;
    allergyList.push(allergyField);
    AllergyString = JSON.stringify(allergyList)
  };
```

Here is the process of storing it to firestore:

```
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, passwords.password).then(function(user){setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('uid',user.user.uid);
        usersRef.doc(user.user.uid).set({
          'email': data.email, 'firstName': data.firstName, 
          'lastName': data.lastName, 'allergies': allergyList,
          'sex': data.sex, 'birthDate': firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(data.birthDate),
          'diabetesType': data.diabetesType, 'diabetesComplication': arrayComplications,
          'weight': data.weight, 'height': data.height, 'firstLogin': true,
     })}, 3000)
```

Hope this helps!